# How is it possible to do binary search on a singly-linked list in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, big-o, binary-search

[This earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19554431/501557) talks about doing binary search over a doubly-linked list in O(n) time. The algorithm in that answer work as follows:

- Go to the middle of the list to do the first comparison.
- If it's equal to the element we're looking for, we're done.
- If it's bigger than the element we're looking for, walk backwards halfway to the start and repeat.
- If it's smaller than the element we're looking for, walk forwards halfway to the start and repeat.

This works perfectly well for a *doubly*-linked list because it's possible to move both forwards and backwards, but this algorithm wouldn't work in a singly-linked list.

Is it possible to make binary search work in time O(n) on a singly-linked list rather than a doubly-linked list?

Comment: @libik, alfasin: Stack Overflow explicitly encourages you to answer your own questions (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I actually think it's really cool that you can do binary search over doubly-linked lists and singly-linked lists, and so I thought I'd share how to do that here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I read it, in that context, it is obvious, that answering question means : "If you ask question and then you find out solution, feel free to answer that question." Definitely there is nothing like : "Create question if you know answer already and then answer the question immediately."

Comment: @libik- There's an explicit checkbox at the "ask a question page" that specifically lets you ask and answer a question at the same time. I am almost positive that this is designed for cases like these, though I could be wrong.

Comment: What's the point of this? Linear search is O(n), so if your binary search is also O(n), it's the same complexity.

Comment: @Barmar the advantage is, like templatetypedef mentioned in the comments below, in a situation where comparison is very expensive, much more than traversing the list.

Comment: "Performing a binary search on linked list is never a good idea , as usually its running time can exceed that of standard (linear) search." -- from [this page](http://www.algo-faq.com/Linked-List/Implement-binary-search-in-Linked-list.php). That page echoes my thoughts w.r.t. that quote.

Comment: I am sorry for setting off such a firestorm here! I didn't mean to cause such a fuss about whether this is a good idea at all, and was hoping to share a cool algorithm with very specific applications with everyone else.

Comment: @templatetypedef it's not hard to notice that you're a good guy and that your intention was good. Please ignore the "background noise" ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's absolutely possible to make this work. In fact, there's pretty much only one change you need to make to the doubly-linked list algorithm to make it work.

The issue with the singly-linked list case is that if you have a pointer to the middle of the list, you can't go backwards to get back to the first quarter of the list. However, if you think about it, you don't need to start from the middle to do this. Instead, you can start at the *front* of the list and walk to the first quarter. This takes (essentially) the same amount of time as before: rather than going backward n / 4 steps, you can start at the front and go forwards n / 4 steps.

Now suppose you've done the first step and are at position n / 4 or 3n / 4. In this case, you're going to have the same problem as before if you need to back up to position n / 8 or position 5n / 8. In the case that you need to get to position n / 8, you can start at the front of the list again and walk forward n / 8 steps. What about the 5n / 8 case? Here's the trick - if you still have pointer to the n / 2 point, then you can start there and walk forwards n / 8 steps, which will take you to the right spot.

More generally, instead of storing a pointer to the middle of the list, store *two* pointers into the list: one at the front of the range where the value might be and one in the middle of the range where the value might be. If you need to advance forward in the list, update the pointer to the start of the range to be the pointer to the middle of the range, then walk the pointer to the middle of the range forward halfway to the end of the range. If you need to advance backward in the list, update the pointer to the middle of the range to be the pointer to the front of the range, then walk forwards halfway.

Overall, this has the exact same time complexity as the doubly-linked case: we take n / 2 steps, then n / 4 steps, then n / 8 steps, etc., which sums up to O(n) total steps. We also only make O(log n) total comparisons. The only difference is the extra pointer we need to keep track of.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The comparison takes O(1), what takes more time is traversing the nodes. So even if you hold pointers to n/2, n/4 and 3n/4 - the time that'll take you to find it will remain O(n).

Further, if you start from the middle and go back(or forward) you might as well compare along the way cause it takes the same amount of time to do another comparison: O(1).

**To sum up:**
Running a binary-search on a linked list makes no sense unless the linked-list is backed up by an array (ArrayList) which allows direct access to its elements in O(1).

Comment: If comparisons are expensive, there's actually a huge benefit to using binary search rather than regular search. The number of steps taken will be marginally higher, but the number of comparisons will be exponentially smaller. If comparisons take much, much longer than advancing in the list, there's a huge benefit to doing the binary search.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question wasn't whether it's possible in less than `O(n)` or whether it makes sense. The question was whether and how it is possible in `O(n)`.

Comment: @templatetypedef At least in Java: you can compare hashCodes and if there's no match to continue and if there's a match - only then to compare. That should be pretty fast! I find it hard to come up with an example where `equals` will be reasonably expensive in such a way that'll motivate me to run a binary-search on a linked-list.

Comment: @alfasin- That's a good point (though the `hashCode` computation might itself be expensive ^_^). Note that Java's `Collections.binarySearch` specifically is designed to work on *any* list and gives the O(n) guarantee with O(log n) comparisons, which leads me to believe that such cases do actually come up. The C++ `std::binary_search` and `std::lower_bound` algorithms also work this way.

Comment: @sepp2k from my past experience in SO, an answer should be upvoted/downvoted according to its *usefulness* - even if it doesn't "cooperate" with the OP.

Comment: Calculating hashcodes is unlikely to be more efficient than comparing directly (calling hashcode on, say, a string, iterates through the whole string, so an equals comparison can actually be more efficient because it can short-circuit). Hashcodes only save you time if they've already been computed before you compare them.

Comment: @templatetypedef you're right about the fact that calculating the hashCode might be expensive as well, and indeed, in *effective Java* Bloch recommends on lazy calculation. The advantage is indeed, only in case you'll be doing multiple comparisons

Comment: a) There's no answer here. And b) it's not useful. It only contains information that everyone already knew (plus your personal opinion).

Comment: @sepp2k I already understood from your downvote that you think its not useful and that everyone already thought about using hashcode instead of equals and that everybody also think that a binary-search on a lined-list is basically a good idea. I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on this one ;)

Comment: Adding to what's already been said, it's not right to say compares are O(1). It depends on the size of the objects being compared. As a practical example of why binary search is better, consider a list of 1000 strings of length 100000. Assuming many of these strings match up to half-way, doing a straight linear search will take around `.5 * .5 * 100000 * 1000 = 25000000` character compares. Doing a binary search will take around `.5 * 100000 * log 1000 = 500000`. The iteration through the list will be in the order of 1000, which is easily dwarfed by the number of character compares.

Comment: @alfasin It wasn't explicitly stated. Since you haven't corrected your answer appropriately, I figured I'd just make it explicit.

Comment: @Dukeling a) it was explicitly stated in the comments b) in the past 15 years I didn't encounter even once a case where a comparison is so expensive as theoretically stated here, further, when a comparison *is* expensive - you won't save the data in a linked-list. c) I will not change my answer, even though it's cool to know how to preform a binary search on a single-linked list - I believe that it's a good idea to warn people to "not try it at home" and to provide a reasonable explanation why.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved by using Double Pointer Method (provided the list is in sorted order) as described here in this research work: http://www.ijcsit.com/docs/Volume%205/vol5issue02/ijcsit20140502215.pdf

Comment: The idea that this is sufficient for a peer-reviewed research paper is surprising.