# Python: binary search in linked list

Tags: python

Having homework with an assignment of implementing a `linked list` with a `binary search` method. Since linked lists are inherently linear, this does seem odd, however the idea is apparently to show that one is able to form the search method and connect it to the LL, essentialy just simulating binary search, since its complexity will not be better then that of linear. So far i have implemented a simple linked list, together with a working linear search method.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, cargo):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.next  = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.cargo

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def add(self, cargo):
        new_node = Node(cargo)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = new_node
        if self.tail != None:
            self.tail.next = new_node
        self.tail = new_node

    def PrintList(self):
        node = self.head
        while node != None:
            print(node.cargo)
            node = node.next

    def length(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current != None:
            count = count + 1
            current = current.get_next()
        return count

    def linSearch(self, cargo):
        current = self.head
        found = False
        while current and found is False:
            if current.get_data() == cargo:
                found = True
            else:
                current = current.get_next()
        return found

    def binSearch(self, cargo):
        LL = LinkedList
        low = 0
        high = LL.length(self)-1

        while low <= high: 
            mid = (low+high)//2
            if self[mid] > cargo:
                high = mid-1
            elif self[mid] < cargo:
                low = mid+1
            else:
                return mid
        return -1

LL = LinkedList()
LL.add(1)
LL.PrintList()
print(LL.linSearch(2))
print(LL.binSearch(1))
```

Current error when running the `binSearch` method is that `object does not support indexing`. Unfortunately, i’m stuck.

Comment: You're trying to index your `LinkedList` when you say `self[mid]`, but it doesn't support indexing (which would be done via a `__getitem__` method). Binary search makes no sense for a singly-linked list in any event; you need to talk to your teacher.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554640/how-is-it-possible-to-do-binary-search-on-a-singly-linked-list-in-on-time

Comment: It sounds like what you really want here is a [Skip List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). I doubt that's what your teacher had in mind, but when I see "binary search" and "singly-linked list" mentioned in the same context, that's the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: I have updated the question somewhat. Apperently, the list could be double linked as well, if that would help.

Comment: No, linked lists (double or not) only allow iterative walking through it. There is no way to skip through it, so there is no use for binary search (which makes use of the ability for random access)