# linear and binary search for list using arrays and linked list

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search, linear-search

So far in the data structure, i have studied about  list using arrays and linked list (single, double, and circular) using a pointer. the next thing in the outline is linear and binary search. I found the examples of the linear search for the list and linked list. for binary search i found an example in list using array but there is no example for linked list (single, double, and circular).
1) I want to know binary search can not apply to any type of the linked list?
2) Also in linear search for single linked list i saw this code

```
if (ptr->data = = SearchElement){
indexPtr = ptr;
return indexPtr;}
```

In this case, when it founds the element it will return the address of the pointer, is it correct? there was no initialization of `indexPtr` so I assumed it is also node type pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do binary search using linked list. Imagine the following is your linked list.

```
1->2->3->4->5->6 and you are searching for 1.
```

You can't get 3rd element in constant time. In binary search you have to jump to an element whenever you want. Consider your linked list is 1 million nodes. Is there a way to go to 500,000th node at constant time? If the answer is yes, in any implementation of linked list, you can find make it in O(log(n)).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554640/how-is-it-possible-to-do-binary-search-on-a-singly-linked-list-in-on-time) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281053/how-to-apply-binary-search-olog-n-on-a-sorted-linked-list) questions & answers.

Linear search code should be something like that.

```
ptr = head;
while (ptr-> next != null)
    if(ptr -> data == searchedElement)
        return ptr;
```

It will return you the pointer pointing the matching node.

It's been some time, I haven't checked but it should be like this.

```
cout << "address of ptr: " << &ptr << " address of node " << ptr << " value inside the node " << *ptr << endl;
```

Comment: 1) binary search can not apply on any Linked  list (single, double, and circular)? 
can you explain more clearly why there is no way to use binary search for linked list?
2) if i want to show the output of the return then it will show address of matching node, is it correct?

Comment: that means we can apply to binary search to those problems when we can access to any element in constant time, like in array, right?

Comment: not exactly, there are types that you access on constant time but you can't  do binary search. Such as hash. Also, for binary search, the array should be sorted. you can do binary search in array, arraylist, vector, matrix when they are sorted.

Comment: So what are the exact reasons for binary search is not working with linked list.