# Understanding these questions about binary search on linear data structures?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search

The answers are (1) and (5) but I am not sure why. Could someone please explain this to me and why the other answers are incorrect. How can I understand how things like binary/linear search will behavior on different data structures?
Thank you
[image]

Comment: While I see what they're going for with (1), do note that you can still implement binary search in O(n) total time and O(log n) comparisons [on a doubly-linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554431/how-is-it-possible-to-do-binary-search-on-a-doubly-linked-list-in-on-time) and [on a singly-linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554640/how-is-it-possible-to-do-binary-search-on-a-singly-linked-list-in-on-time).

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you already know about binary search.

(1) True-
Explanation 
For performing binary search, we have to get to middle of the sorted list. In linked list to get to the middle of the list we have to traverse half of the list starting from the head, while in array we can directly get to middle index if we know the length of the list. So linked lists takes O(n/2) time which can be done in O(1) by using array. Therefore linked list is not the efficient way to implement binary search.

(2)False

Same explanation as above

(3)False
Explanation

As explained in point 1 linked list cannot be used efficiently to perform binary search but array can be used.

(4) False
Explanation

Binary search worst case time is O(logn). As in binary search we don't need to traverse the whole list. In first loop if key is lesser then middle value we will discard the second half of the list. Similarly now we will operate with the remaining list. As we can see with every loop we are discarding the part of the list that we don't have to traverse, so clearly it will take less then O(n).

(5)True
Explanation

If element is found in O(1) time, that means only one loop was run by the code. And in the first loop we always compare to the middle element of the list that means the search will take O(1) time only if the middle element is the key value.

Answer (score 0):

In short, binary search is an elimination based searching technique that can be applied when the elements are sorted. The idea is to eliminate half the keys from consideration by keeping the keys in sorted order. If the search key is not equal to the middle element, one of the two sets of keys to the left and to the right of the middle element can be eliminated from further consideration.

Now coming to your specific question,

1. True

The basic binary search requires that mid-point can be found in O(1) time which can't be possible in linked list and can be way more expensive if the the size of the list is unknown.
True.

2. False
3. False

Binary search, mid-point calculation should be done in O(1) time which can only be possible in arrays , as the indices defined in arrays are known. Secondly binary search can only be applied to the arrays which are in sorted order.

4. False

The answer by Vaibhav Khandelwal, explained it nicely. But I wanted to add some variations of the array on to which binary search can be still applied. If the given array is sorted but rotated by X degree and contains duplicates, for example,

```
3 5 6 7 1 2 3 3 3
```

Then binary search still applies on it, but for the worst case, we needed we go linearly through this list to find the required element, which is O(n).

5. True

If the element found in the first attempt i.e situated at the mid-point then it would be processed in O(1) time.

```
MidPointOfArray = (LeftSideOfArray + RightSideOfArray)/ 2
```

The best way to understand binary search is to think of exam papers which are sorted according to last names. In order to find a particular student paper, the teacher has to search in that student name's category and rule-out the ones that are not alphabetically closer to the name of the student.
For example, if the name is Alex Bob, then teacher directly starts her search from "B", then take out all the copies that have surname "B", then again repeat the process, and skips the copies till letter "o" and so on till find it or not.