# Binary search of LinkedList

Tags: java

I am trying to do a binary search on nodes in a sorted linked list. Not only am I struggling with the algorithm I can't seen to get the while loop to fire. I am using the compareto() method to find the item in the list. The rest of the program works fine except this method. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void contNameBinSearch()
{
    int beg = 0;  
    int mid = (contTable.size()/2);
    int end = contTable.size()-1;
    int binFind;
    String findBin;
    boolean findBinName = false;

    System.out.print("Please enter contributor's last name for binary search: \r\n");
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    findBin = sn.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    findBinName = contTable.get(mid).getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(findBin);

    binFind = findBin.compareTo(contTable.get(mid).getLastName()); 

    System.out.print("initial beg " + beg + "\r\n");
    System.out.print("initial mid " + mid + "\r\n");
    System.out.print("initial end " + end + "\r\n");    

    while (findBinName = false)
    {
        System.out.print("Test Point 1");

        if (binFind == 0) 
             {
                 System.out.print("Test Point 2");
                 findBinName = true;
                 break;
             }

        else if (binFind > 0)
             {
                 System.out.print("Test Point 3");
                 mid = end -(end - mid)/2;
                 end = mid + mid/2;
             } 

        else if (binFind < 0)
             {
                 System.out.print("Test Point 4");
                 end = mid;
                 mid = mid/2;                     
             } 

    }

        if (findBinName)
             {   
                 System.out.print(contTable.get(mid).getData() + "\r\n");
             }
        else
             {
                 System.out.print("User " + findBin + " does not exist please try again.\r\n\r\n");
                 contNameBinSearch();
             }

     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: A binary search works best when you have random access to a list.  Are you sure using a binary search for a linked list make sense?

Comment: I dont see the code where you get the mid element after computing the mid value

Comment: Peter, Using a binary search is a requirement for this assignment for a class. 
Kakarot, I'm not sure I know what you mean? mid is an integer used as the middle of the list's indexes. I'm splitting the list to break up the parts in two (binary) and also used as the index of the item in the linked list for the get() method. Getting the variables to be stable and update as needed is still another issue.

Comment: I think linear search is the quickest search algorithm for LinkedLists. And one advantage the list doesn't have to be sorted. (next time say it when it is for homework)

Comment: Binary search may be a requirement, but is a linked list also a requirement?

Comment: If `contTable` is a linked-list, then you're algorithm takes O(n log n), which is worse than an O(n) linear search.

Comment: Related - [How is it possible to do binary search on a doubly-linked list in O(n) time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19554431) (presumably quite a bit beyond what you'd be required to do, but interesting nonetheless)

Comment: David, sadly yes. The course was written by an idiot.

Comment: martijnn, sorry, I missed spelling out it was an assignment. I'm relatively new to posting here although this community's wisdom has helped me immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`while (findBinName = false)`

to

`while (findBinName == false)`

or even better to

`while (!findBinName)`

In the former version, the value false is assigned to `findBinName`, then the value of `findBinName` is tested but it's already false. So your loop never executes.

Comment: Peter, thank you, that seems to help a little, at least now I get into the loop. Now I need to figure out the rest of the algorithm for bouncing back and forth doing the search.