# Is binary search for an ordered list O(logN) in Elixir?

Tags: time-complexity, elixir, binary-search

For an ordered list, the binary search time complexity is O(logN). However in Elixir, the list is linked list, so in order to get the middle element of the list, you have to iterate N/2 times, which make the overall search O(NLogN).

So my question is:

> 1. Is above time complexity correct?
> 2. If it's correct, the binary search wouldn't make sense in Elixir, right? You have to iterate the list to get what you want, so the best is O(N).

Comment: This should help you understand why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554431/how-is-it-possible-to-do-binary-search-on-a-doubly-linked-list-in-on-time?rq=1

Comment: Yep, you're better off with linear search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is little reason to binary search over a linked list because of the reason you stated. You need a random access data structure (usually an array) for binary search to be useful.

An interesting corner case might arise where the comparison of the elements is very costly, because for example they are just handles to remotely stored items. In that case binary search through a linked list might still outperform linear search, because while requiring more operations (`O(N * log(N))`) it requires less comparisons (`O(log(N))`) while linear search requires `O(N)` comparisons.